# Is it safe to interrupt a write to a file (with Python)?

Tags: python, corruption

Is there any risk related to interrupting a write to a file? Be it closing a GUI program in the middle of a write, keyboard interruptions, what have you. My main concern is that it might corrupt some other unrelated data in my drive. I want to make sure it's safe since it's important data that I'm dealing with. Also, would the risk (if any) differ depending on the operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless "interruptions" includes power loss or crashing the system, interrupting a program is NOT going to corrupt any files that it does not have open for write.

Note that coding errors in other programs that expect useful data from the program you killed may end up losing or corrupting other files - e.g. if you have a shell script that runs your python script in order to get the name of a directory to delete but doesn't bother to check the exit code (or the validity of the returned directory name) from the python script before performing the deletion, it could conceivably delete a directory you don't want it to.   e.g. `dir=$(my-python-program); rm -rf "./$dir"` can delete everything from the current dir down because there's no error-checking between the assignment and the deletion.   But this is a problem caused by sloppy and lazy programming, not by interrupting/killing programs.

---

BTW, if your data is important and you can't risk losing it then **work on a copy of the data** and/or **backup the data before doing anything with it**.   That way, you will always have the original data to make another working copy from if something goes wrong.  **NEVER** work on the original or only copy of data.

Personally, I tend to do that even with fairly unimportant data - if I mess it up, I can revert to the original and make another copy to work with.